# colocate_gradients_with_ops argument in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to understand what this argument does, the [TF api docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/api_docs/python/tf/train/AdamOptimizer#compute_gradients) for AdamOptimizer's `compute_gradients` method say the following -

`colocate_gradients_with_ops`: If True, try colocating gradients with the corresponding op.

but it is not clear to me. What does colocating gradients mean in this context and what is the said op?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

colocate_gradients_with_ops=False (default): compute gradients on a single GPU (most likely /gpu:0)

colocate_gradients_with_ops=True: compute gradients on multiple GPUs in parallel.

In more detail:

**colocate_gradients_with_ops=False (default)**

Only computes predictions in parallel and then move the computed predictions to the parameter server(cpu:0 or gpu:0). And with predictions, the parameter server (**single device**) computes gradients for the whole batch (gpu_count * batch_size).

**colocate_gradients_with_ops=True**

Place the computation of gradients on the same device as the original (forward-pass) op.
Namely, compute gradients together with predictions on each particular GPU and then move the gradients to the parameter server to average them to get the overall gradients.

[Reference 1 @mrry](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2441)

[Reference 2 @bzamecnik](https://github.com/kuza55/keras-extras/issues/21)